# How to properly assign a pandas dataframe slice to values in another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

although I solved this problem already, I was wondering, whether there is a more direct way of achieving my assignment.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'position': ['20', '8000', '8000'],
                   'SNP_ID': ['rs01', 'rs02', 'rs03'],
                   'SNP_ref': ['A', 'C', 'T'],
                   'SNP_alts': ['G', 'T','A,G,']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'position': ['400', '8000', '90000'],
                   'SNP_ID': ['', '', ''],
                   'SNP_ref': ['', '', ''],
                   'SNP_alts': ['', '',''],
                   'check_ref':['T','T','A'],
                   'check_alts':['T','G','A'],
                   'other_data': ['xx','yy','zz']})

c1 = ['SNP_ID','SNP_ref','SNP_alts']

for i in range(len(df2)):

    SNVs = df1[df1['position'] == df2['position'].loc[i]]

    if not SNVs.empty:
        df2.loc[df2.index[i],c1] = SNVs.loc[SNVs['SNP_ref'] == df2['check_ref'].loc[i],c1].iloc[0]

        print(df2)
```

So essentially based on some criteria (more than shown here), I want to assign the values of three columns for a given row (based on some criteria) to three columns in another df. I only got this to work using .tolist().

Is there any more straightforward way of achieving this?

*note: I'm aware that looping over rows in a df is not good practice, but with my knowledge I'm currently unable to come up with a better solution and I have to do more comparisons to decide which rows to copy. For now my dfs are fairly small, so time is not a big issue.

Thanks
Hagen

*UPDATE:
based on the answers I modified my code again with a more realistic dataset, and got it to work without .tolist()

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'position': ['20', '8000', '8000'],
                   'SNP_ID': ['rs01', 'rs02', 'rs03'],
                   'SNP_ref': ['A', 'C', 'T'],
                   'SNP_alts': ['G', 'T','A,G,']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'position': ['400', '8000', '90000'],
                   'SNP_ID': ['', '', ''],
                   'SNP_ref': ['', '', ''],
                   'SNP_alts': ['', '',''],
                   'check_ref':['T','T','A'],
                   'check_alts':['T','G','A'],
                   'other_data': ['xx','yy','zz']})

c1 = ['SNP_ID','SNP_ref','SNP_alts']

for i in range(len(df2)):

    SNVs = df1[df1['position'] == df2['position'].loc[i]]

    if not SNVs.empty:
        df2.loc[df2.index[i],c1] = SNVs.loc[SNVs['SNP_ref'] == df2['check_ref'].loc[i],c1].iloc[0]

print(df2)
```

*Update 2 with additional comparison no checking whether letter ('A', 'T', etc) are matched in *_alts, but SNP_alts can contain multiple sequences seperated by colons (e.g. A,T,G,AA,GG)

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'position': ['20', '8000', '8000'],
                   'SNP_ID': ['rs01', 'rs02', 'rs03'],
                   'SNP_ref': ['A', 'C', 'T'],
                   'SNP_alts': ['G', 'T','A,G,']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'position': ['400', '8000', '90000'],
                   'SNP_ID': ['', '', ''],
                   'SNP_ref': ['', '', ''],
                   'SNP_alts': ['', '',''],
                   'check_ref':['T','T','A'],
                   'check_alts':['T','G','A'],
                   'other_data': ['xx','yy','zz']})

c1 = ['SNP_ID','SNP_ref','SNP_alts']

for i in range(len(df2)):

    SNVs = df1[df1['position'] == df2['position'].loc[i]]

    if not SNVs.empty:
        bm1 = SNVs['SNP_ref'] == df2['check_ref'].loc[i]
        bm2 = SNVs['SNP_alts'].apply(lambda x: True if df2['check_alts'].loc[i] in x.split(',') else False)

        if len(SNVs.loc[bm1 & bm2,c1])>0:
            df2.loc[df2.index[i],c1] = SNVs.loc[bm1 & bm2,c1].iloc[0]

print(df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with rename columns for correct match:

```
c1 = ['SNP_ID','SNP_ref','SNP_alts']
c2 = ['name','ref','alts']
d = dict(zip(c2, c1))

#for align values by column position
df11 = df1.set_index(['position','SNP_ref'])
df22 = df2.set_index(['position','check_ref'])
    
df22.update(df11.rename(columns=d))
df22 = df22.reset_index().reindex(df2.columns, axis=1)
print (df22)

  position SNP_ID SNP_ref SNP_alts check_ref other_data
0      400                                 T         xx
1     8000   rs03                A         T         yy
2    90000                                 A         zz
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but as far as I can see this only works on entire columns, but I only want to modify one row at a time (and not all rows). So essentially update a slice of df1.

Comment: @HagenW - Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: agreed information was too limited , I wanted to avoid my second "problem" looping over dfs. I hope it is much clearer now.

Comment: @HagenW - Answer was edited.

Comment: @HagenW - Answer was edited with `drop_duplicates`

Comment: thanks for taking the time, unfortunately my example dataset was not realistic enough, I added an updated to my code and data again, but somehow also made it work without going via a list ... Anyway I find indexing of pandas dfs really confusing at least in comparison to R

Comment: I can't drop duplicates, but have to select the correct one (see second code example).

Comment: @HagenW - OK, sems need set_index by both columns, answer was EDITed.

Comment: Ok I modified the data and code with the last bit, that I actually need, would you still come up with an index based version? Btw. this is real world data, not made up, I also have to check SNP_alts agains a check_alts, but SNP_alts can contain a list of letters or short sequence of letters seperated by colons. I modified my code below using lambda and split to check for this. Would be much interested if you have a better solution again.